# How can I find out how frequently certain words are used in Danish print and online news media?

Tags: data-request, media

Do you know of any sites that make this information available online?

Answer (score 2):

Some data is available if you [Google for danish word frequency](https://www.google.com/search?q=danish+word+frequency) or [danish word list](https://www.google.com/search?q=danish+word+list), but you'll have to check if those results are good enough for you. Or search with the Danish equivalent for those words.

The [Wiktionary list based on movie subtitles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/Danish_wordlist) looks nice.

Alas, the first suspect, [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams), doesn't have Danish data.